# What is the difference between fit() and fit_generator() in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

What is the difference between [`fit()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) and [`fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) in Keras?

When should I use `fit()` vs `fit_generator()`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In keras, `fit()` is much similar to sklearn's fit method, where you pass array of features as x values and target as y values. You pass your whole dataset at once in fit method. Also, use it if you can load whole data into your memory (small dataset).

In `fit_generator()`, you don't pass the x and y directly, instead they come from a **generator**. As it is written in [keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), generator is used when you want to avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing. This is for practical purpose, when you have large dataset.

Here is a link to understand more about this-

[A thing you should know about Keras if you plan to train a deep learning model on a large dataset](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-a-thing-you-should-know-about-keras-if-you-plan-to-train-a-deep-learning-model-on-a-large-fdd63ce66bd2)

For reference you can check this book- https://github.com/hktxt/bookshelf/blob/master/Computer%20Science/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Python%2C%20Fran%C3%A7ois%20Chollet.pdf

Comment: Hi Ankit,  your link http://www.deeplearningitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Dropbox_Chollet.pdf doesn’t work . Do you have a working link.

Comment: @ChiduMurthy Thanks for the info. I have edited the link.

Comment: According to documentation, we can also pass generators to fit method. So I still don't understand why we need a separate fit_generator method?
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: `.fit_generator` method is currently in the process of deprecation.

Answer (score 3):

**There is more to the difference between Keras `fit` and `fit.generator` than meets the eye.** I had a dataset who was perfectly been learned by the model using `fit.generator`. As the dataset wasn't too big I decided to change to `fit` instead of `fit.generator`. To my surprise the learning curve was all over the place. Had to start tuning up from scratch.
Guess the way gradients are updated in each function differs quite significantly. Beware.